# Java collections API: why are Unmodifiable[List|Set|Map] not publicly visible classes?

Tags: java, api, collections, unmodifiable

`Collections.unmodifiableList(...)` returns a new instance of a **static inner class** `UnmodifiableList`. Other unmodifiable collections classes are constructed same way.

**Were** these classes public, one had two advantages:

- ability to indicate a more specific return value (such as `UnmodifiableList`), so an API user wouldn't come to the idea of modifying that collection;
- ability to check during runtime if a `List` is `instanceof UnmodifiableList`.

So, were there any advantages **not** to make those classes public?

**EDIT**: No definitely convincing arguments were presented, so I choose the most upvoted answer.

Comment: Why would you need to do that?

Comment: Quick! Someone contact Joshua Bloch! I don't know his email...

Comment: Joshua Bloch [has a Twitter account](http://twitter.com/joshbloch), for anyone that knows how to operate Twitter...

Comment: @Thorbjørn - well, someone might want to specify that a method's return type was *immutable* and should not be modified. Personally I think there should be an `Immutable` interface, like scala. Unfortunately Java's crap typesystem would not allow you to specify an intersection of types as a type in its own right (i.e. `public <Map with Immutable> foo`)

Comment: @osbow_lakes, I don't follow the argument.  There exists plenty of classes which only implement some functionality of the appropriate interface, and leave the rest to throw UnsupportedOperationException.    Why do you need more than that?

Comment: I think they would be useful for solving problems like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861228/how-to-handle-a-findbugs-non-transient-non-serializable-instance-field-in-seria)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think both advantages are there but are not that useful. The main problems remain the same: UnmodifiableList still is a List and thus all the setters are available and the underlying collections still are modifiable. Making the class UnmodifiableList public would add to the illusion of being unmodifiable.

The nicer way would be for the compiler to help, but for that the collection class hierarchies would have to changed a lot. E.g., the collection API of Scala is way more advanced in that respect.

A disadvantage would be the introduction of at least three additional classes / interfaces into the API. Because of them not being that useful, I think leaving them out of the API is a good choice.

Comment: Better fail fast (at compile time, not at runtime). So the additional interfaces for unmodifiable collections are worth the effort.

Answer (score 9):

Personally I completely agree with you. At the core of the problem is that fact that Java's generics are not covariant, which, in turn, is because Java's collections are mutable.

It is not possible for Java's type system to codify a type that seems to have *mutators* is *actually immutable*. Imagine if we were to start designing some solution:

```
interface Immutable //marker for immutability

interface ImmutableMap<K, V> extends Map<K, V>, Immutable
```

But then `ImmutableMap` is a subclass of `Map`, and hence `Map` is assignable from `ImmutableMap` so any method which returns such an immutable Map:

```
public ImmutableMap<K, V> foo();
```

can be assigned to a Map and can therefore be mutated at compile time:

```
Map<K, V> m = foo();
m.put(k, v); //oh dear
```

So, you can see that the addition of this type has not actually prevented us from doing anything bad. I think for this reason a judgement was made that it did not have enough to offer.

---

A language like **scala** has declaration-site variance annotations. That is, you could specify a type as being covariant (and hence immutable) as Scala's Map is (actually it's covariant in its `V` parameter). Hence your API can declare whether its return type is mutable or immutable.

As another aside, Scala lets you declare intersection types so that you don't even need to create the `ImmutableXYZ` interface as a separate entity, you could specify a method to return:

```
def foo : XYZ with Immutable
```

But then scala has a proper type system, whereas Java does not

Comment: `ImmutableMap` extending `Map` is a design mistake we would have made. `ImmutableMap` must have a `Map` (the composition relationship).

Answer (score 4):

The answer to the why is quite simple: at the time, in 1998, efficient design was a bit flanky. People thought about it it wasn't apparently a priority. But there was no true, deep thinking about it.

If you want to use such a mechanism, use Guava's ImmutableList/Set/Map/...

They are explicitly Immutable and a good practice when using that library is not to return a List for instance but an ImmutableList. So you will know that a List/Set/Map/... is immutable.

Example:

```
private final ImmutableList constants = ...;
public final ImmutableList<String> getConstants() {
  return constants;
}
```

About the design itself of UnmodifiableXxx, one could have done the following:

```
public static final class UnmodifiableXxx implements Xxx { // don't allow extend
  // static if inside Collections
  UnmodifiableXxx (Xxx backend) { // don't allow direct instanciation
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Top answer according to me. Here sir, have an upvote. Unfortunately few people grasp design the way you do.

Answer (score 3):

If it important for you to check if the list was created with Collections.unmodifiableList then you can create an instance and ask for the class. Now you you can compare this class with the class of any list.

```
private static Class UNMODIFIABLE_LIST_CLASS = 
    Collections.unmodifiableList( new ArrayList() ).getClass();
...
if( UNMODIFIABLE_LIST_CLASS == listToTest.getClass() ){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `UnmodifiableList` *was* a public class. I suspect that it would lull programmers into a false sense of security. Remember, `UnmodifiableList` is a *view* of a *modifiable* `List`. This means that the contents of an `UnmodifiableList` can still change via any changes made to its underlying `List`. A naive programmer may not understand this nuance and may expect instances of `UnmodifiableList` to be immutable.

Comment: Well, with same arguments one could argue against `Collections.unmodifiable[List|Map|Set]`...

Comment: @java.is.for.desktop: I had thought about that too. At least the current way forces the programmer to see the underlying `List` being passed to the method. If you saw an `UnmodifiableList` sitting out in the wild, some programmers may not realize that it originated via `Collections.unmodifiableList`. I know this is grasping at straws. Just an opinion. :)

Answer (score 1):

> - ability to indicate a more specific return value (such as `UnmodifiableList`), so an API user wouldn't come to the idea of modifying that collection;

In a proper API, this should already be documented in the javadoc of the method returning the unmodifiable list.

> - ability to check during runtime if a `List` is `instanceof UnmodifiableList`.

Such a need indicates that the *actual* problem lies somewhere else. It's a flaw in the code design. Ask yourself, have you ever had the need to check if a `List` is an instance of `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`? Whether it's an `ArrayList`, `LinkedList` or `UnmodifiableList` is clearly a decision which is to be made during code write time, not during code run time. If you're encountering problems because you're attempting to modify an `UnmodifiableList` (for which the API developer may have very good reasions which should be already documented), then it's rather your own fault, not a runtime fault.

All with all, it makes no sense. The `Collections#unmodifiableXXX()`, `synchronizedXXX()` and `checkedXXX()` do in any way not represent concrete implementations. They are all just [**decorators**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) which can be applied regardless of the underlying concrete implementation.

Comment: I think they would be useful for solving problems like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861228/how-to-handle-a-findbugs-non-transient-non-serializable-instance-field-in-seria)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is because the method form properly knows about the generics used and requires no extra programming to pass this information through, whilst the class form would require more messing about. The method form for `unmodifiableMap` has two floating generic arguments, which it maps to both the generic arguments of the return type and of the passed argument.

```
public static <K,V> Map<K,V> unmodifiableMap(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
    return new UnmodifiableMap<K,V>(m);
}
```

Comment: Well, the factory methods `Collections.unmodifiable[...](...)` could be used even with publicly available classes.